# If statement to determine which SELECT to return in Table-Valued Function

Tags: sql, sql-server

Due to a recent change in business rules, a certain set of data used to be stored in one database and is now stored in a different database on the same server. As things are currently set up, if a user wants to query data from a range of dates which overlaps the time when business rules were changed, they're forced to use an IF statement in their code.

I would like to create a table-valued function that will abstract this change in business rules for users making such a query. Currently I'm trying to execute code similar to this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.someFunction (date DATETIME)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
IF (date <= business_rules_change_date)
BEGIN
SELECT (A select statement)
FROM (Old Database)
WHERE (criteria)
END
ELSE
SELECT (A similar select statement)
FROM (New Database)
JOIN (A Join Statement)
WHERE (criteria)
GO
```

and I'm being told that there is a syntax error around the IF statement. Is there a good solution to my problem?

Comment: I removed the mysql tag because the syntax is SQL Server and MySQL doesn't support table valued functions.

Comment: Yours is "inline table-valued function". Look into "multi-statement table-valued function" - they allow for flow control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or as Yuriy has suggested you can make use of Multi-statement-table valued functions something like this...

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.someFunction (date DATETIME)
RETURNS @TABLE TABLE 
(
     -- Define the structure of table here
)
AS
BEGIN
  IF (date <= business_rules_change_date)
   BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @TABLE
    SELECT (A select statement)
    FROM (Old Database)
    WHERE (criteria)
   END  
ELSE
  BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO @TABLE
    SELECT (A similar select statement)
    FROM (New Database)
    JOIN (A Join Statement)
    WHERE (criteria)
  END

  RETURN    
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.someFunction (date DATETIME)
  RETURNS @RtnTable TABLE (SomeValue varchar(250))
AS
BEGIN
  IF (date <= business_rules_change_date)
  BEGIN
     INSERT INTO @RtnTable
     SELECT (A select statement)
     FROM (Old Database)
     WHERE (criteria)
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN 
     INSERT INTO @RtnTable
     SELECT (A similar select statement)
     FROM (New Database)
     JOIN (A Join Statement)
     WHERE (criteria)
  END

  RETURN
END
```

This example assumes that your function returns a resultset with a single varchar column. Based on your IF condition you can populate it with results of different SELECT statement. Adjust it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Inline table-valued functions cannot contain an IF statement.  You could reorganize your query this way:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.someFunction (date DATETIME)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
    SELECT (A select statement)
    FROM (Old Database)
    WHERE (criteria) AND (date <= business_rules_change_date)
    UNION
    SELECT (A similar select statement)
    FROM (New Database)
    JOIN (A Join Statement)
    WHERE (criteria) AND (date > business_rules_change_date)
GO
```